# How to write a seek/keyset pagination query using sequelize for postgres dialect?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a raw SQL query written in pg-promise that looks as shown below

```
SELECT
    f.feed_item_id,
    pubdate,
    link,
    guid,
    title,
    summary,
    author,
    feed_id,
    COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes,
    COALESCE(dislikes, 0) AS dislikes,
    COALESCE(bullish, 0) AS bullish,
    COALESCE(bearish, 0) AS bearish,
    tags 
FROM
    feed_items f 
    LEFT JOIN
        feed_item_likes_dislikes_aggregate l 
        ON f.feed_item_id = l.feed_item_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        feed_item_bullish_bearish_aggregate b 
        ON f.feed_item_id = b.feed_item_id 
WHERE
    (
        pubdate,
        f.feed_item_id
    )
    < ($1, $2) 
ORDER BY
    pubdate DESC,
    f.feed_item_id DESC LIMIT $3
```

How can I rewrite this query using sequelize?

My current attempt comes like this

```
FeedItem.findAll({
    attributes: [
            'feedItemId',
            'pubdate',
            'link',
            'guid',
            'title',
            'summary',
            'author',
            'feedId',
            'tags',
            [sequelize.fn('COALESCE', sequelize.col('bullish'), 0), 'bullish'],
            [sequelize.fn('COALESCE', sequelize.col('bearish'), 0), 'bearish'],
            [sequelize.fn('COALESCE', sequelize.col('likes'), 0), 'likes'],
            [sequelize.fn('COALESCE', sequelize.col('dislikes'), 0), 'dislikes'],
        ],
    include: [{
        model: FeedItemBullishBearishAggregate,
        attributes: [],
    }, {
        model: FeedItemLikesDislikesAggregate,
        attributes: [],
    }],
    order: [
        ['pubdate', 'DESC'],
        ['feedItemId', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit: 1
}).then(a).catch(b)
```

How do I put that where condition in the above findAll expression?

Comment: Doesn't SQL look much better? Why rewrite it in the first place? :)

Comment: Can you explain what does this condition mean?